# writing a list or array to file

Tags: python

Example of the temp.txt file:

> File: t091110_065921.SFTC Src: J1903+0925 Nsub: 1 Nch: 1 Npol: 4 Nbin: 1024 RMS: 0.00118753
>   0 0 0 0.00148099 -0.00143755 0.000931365 -0.00296775
>   0 0 1 0.000647476 -0.000896698 0.000171287 0.00218597
>   0 0 2 0.000704697 -0.00052846 -0.000603842 -0.000868739
>   .
>   .
>   etc..

Thank you!

---

In response to how this was generated, I used the following code:

```
for i in range(numrows):
    epoch_name = y['filename'][i]
    os.system('pdv -t {0} > temp.txt '.format(epoch_name))
    stokes_line = np.genfromtxt('temp.txt', usecols=3, dtype=[('stokesI','float')], skip_header=1)
    stokes_list.append(stokes_line)
stokes_columns = zip(*stokes_list)
```

So I am using some other software with the "pdv" command to generate a grid of values each time the programme loops (into a text file). Then I pull out 1 particular column from this text file and add it to "stokes_list". Finally I transpose the array (or whatever it is) so that the columns become rows.

---

I have in Python, a list of lists (or any array, I don't understand the terminology really) that looks something like:

```
[((1,)(2,)(3,)),((4,)(5,)(6,)),((7,)(8,)(9,))]
```

Firstly, I'm not sure why it has parentheses inside the square brackets, as opposed to square brackets within square brackets. Secondly, I don't know why the numbers have a comma after them and themselves appear in parentheses. Anyway - perhaps more context is needed to answer this. But my real problem, is that I am trying to write this out to a file in the format:

```
1   2   3  
4   5   6  
7   8   9
```

I am trying:

```
with open('final.txt','w') as f:
    for row in stokes_columns:
        f.write('\t'.join(row)+'\n')
```

Where "stokes_columns" is the name of my array / list at the top.

I am getting the error message:

```
f.write('\t'.join(row)+'\n')
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, numpy.void found
```

Could anyone help me with this please?

Comment: The structure you have above is not a simple list of lists, or a list of tuples- it is generated by `numpy`. How was it generated?

Comment: You can not apply join() to a sequence of integers.

Comment: I don't think `((1,)(2,)(3,))` is meaningful in python. Are some commas missing?

Comment: @Eric: As hinted at by the TypeError, it looks like this is something from `numpy` that shows up like that as a string (`numpy` can have somewhat funny formatting in their `__repr__`).

Comment: is the string like this `[((1,),(2,),(3,)),((4,),(5,),(6,)),((7,),(8,),(9,))]` ??

Comment: Can you give an example of the content of `temp.txt`?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, the format has more commas: [((1,),(2,),(3,)),((4,),(5,),(6,)),((7,),(8,),(9,))] is how it looks

Comment: We can't answer unless we know what is loaded from temp.txt. Could you provide an example?

Comment: I have provided now as an edit to my original post, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the way to create or transpose a numpy matrix (especially since it's not a numpy matrix- it's a regular list of numpy vectors). Try the following:

```
stokes_list = np.array([])
for i in range(numrows):
    epoch_name = y['filename'][i]
    os.system('pdv -t {0} > temp.txt '.format(epoch_name))
    stokes_line = np.genfromtxt('temp.txt', usecols=3, dtype=[('stokesI','float')], skip_header=1)
    stokes_list = vstack(stokes_list, stokes_line)

stokes_columns = np.transpose(stokes_list)
```

Comment: I'm probably being dumb but I got this error straight away: stokes_list = np.array()
TypeError: Required argument 'object' (pos 1) not found

Answer (score 2):

`join` requires an array of strings. Your 3rd line should be:

```
f.write('\t'.join(str(cell) for cell in row)+'\n')
```

You can do the entire thing in one statement, if you want:

```
f.write('\n'.join(
    '\t'.join(str(cell) for cell in row)
    for row in stokes_columns
))
```

Comment: This is not a list of lists (or tuples or anything like that): it looks like it's a `numpy` object (I'm not 100% sure which) that apparently prints in this way. See the TypeError- this won't solve the problem.

Comment: I realize its a numpy object - however, I'd still expect it to be iterable

Comment: I don't think it'll give what he's looking for. But I'll remove the downvote while it's unclear.

Comment: You're probably right, but I don't have a numpy install to test with.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the list you specified (which i think is not what it should be)

assuming it is `[((1,),(2,),(3,)),((4,),(5,),(6,)),((7,),(8,),(9,))]`

The following should help you to some extent

Once you get the final output, you can use it to push it to the rows

```
In [74]: str = [((1,),(2,),(3,)),((4,),(5,),(6,)),((7,),(8,),(9,))]

In [75]: str2 = []

In [76]: for elem in str:
   ....:     str2.append([data[0] for data in elem])
   ....:

In [77]: str2
Out[77]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

In [78]: for elem in zip(*str2):
   ....:     print elem
   ....:
(1, 4, 7)
(2, 5, 8)
(3, 6, 9)
```

As per OP's last edit, changed the output:

```
In [92]: for elem in str2:
   ....:     print elem
   ....:
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not trying tow write a list of tuples but a numpy array with a flexible datatype (`void` in this case, accordingly to your `TypeError`). Flexible dtypes have not predefined size so before you save it you should decide which dtype you want to use for storing your array. For instance, assuming that you want to store your data as int16 you can do:

```
your_array.astype('int16').tofile(filename)
```

I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

the tofile() function writes all items **(as machine values)** to the file object f.
Maybe `savetxt()` is the right function for am ascii-file